# updating the object which is exported across the project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following object which is shared with other files

/utils/token

```js
module.exports = (function() {
  const cache = {
    access_token: 'jhkjfdhgkjhfkjmvbnmvcmgkjcvbnbfjhxvnm',
    expires_in: 2592000,
    token_type: 'Bearer'
  };
  return {
    get(key) {
      return cache[key];
    },
    set(key, val) {
      cache[key] = val;
    }
  };
}());
```

In other file I'm trying to update the object with SET Method

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const _ = require('lodash');

const config = require('../config');
const axios = require('axios');
const errors = require('../utils/errors');
const constants = require('../utils/constants');
const jwtTokenService = require('../utils/jwt-token-service');
const cache = require('../utils/jwtToken'); // imported up here

router.get('/', (req, res) => {

  const httpSearchAddressUXConfig = {
    headers: Object.assign(res._headers, {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${cache.get('access_token')}` // I am using get function to retrieve the value
    }),
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://getUser/12345',
    timeout: config.app.enterpriseHTTPTimeout
  };
  axios(httpSearchAddressUXConfig)
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      const errorList = err.response.data.errorList;
      // res.status(401).json(errorList);
      _.forEach(errorList, (element) => {
        if (element.code === 'AUTH0007' || element.code === 'AUTH0003') {
          jwtTokenService.getJwtToken(req, res).then((data) => {
              cache.set('access_token', data.access_token); //updating the value up here
              return axios(httpSearchAddressUXConfig); 

// when I make this call it is taking the default value from the /utils/token through GET

            })
            .then(response => res.status(200).json(response))
            .catch((errResponse) => {
              res.status(401).json(errResponse.response.data.errorList);
            });
        }
      });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Above SET method works fine but the value of cache.access_token is not getting updated. so I need to make a set call every-time I need an updated token.

I would like to change the value of cache.access_token when ever SET method is called and have that value accessible through GET in all end points

```js
const cache = {
  access_token: 'jhkjfdhgkjhfkjmvbnmvcmgkjcvbnbfjhxvnm', 
// need to change when ever SET is called.
  expires_in: 2592000,
  token_type: 'Bearer'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to generate the axios config. You have created the config once, by calling `cache.get('access_token')`, using the same object will not invoke `cache.get` again. Use a function like this

```
function makeAxiosConfig(headers) {
  return {
    headers: Object.assign({}, headers, {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${cache.get('access_token')}`
    }),
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://getUser/12345',
    timeout: config.app.enterpriseHTTPTimeout
   }
}

// then inside you express middleware use it as follows
axios(makeAxiosConfig(res._headers)).then(() => {
  // do something
}).catch(ex => {
  // update token
  return axios(makeAxiosConfig(res._header);
});
```

Comment: is the value is updated and saved in memory ? value is not getting updated in file if I use SET method

Comment: Yeah, the value is loaded into memory. You have to explicitly write to file if you want to change values there.